# Matching two comma seperated strings in Python and correct position counts

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hope get assistance on the below problem.

Python having more in-built sequence matcher functions. Whether the following requirement can be done through any built-in function without looping.

```
x = 'hu1_X','hu2_Y','hu3_H','hu4_H','hu5_H','hu7_H'

y = 'hu1_H','hu2_X','hu3_H','hu4_H','hu5_H','hu7_X'
```

for comparing the above string the final match count is 3.

Matches are:  `'hu3_H'`,`'hu4_H'`,`'hu5_H'`.

Any idea, which in-built function can use? Can we go with ZIP() in Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you actually *tried*? Have you read up on `zip`? Are `x` and `y` actually lists?

Comment: @jonrsharpe As it is, `x` and `y` are tuples :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression and the builtin `sum` function along with `zip`, like this

```
x = 'hu1_X', 'hu2_Y', 'hu3_H', 'hu4_H', 'hu5_H', 'hu7_H'
y = 'hu1_H', 'hu2_X', 'hu3_H', 'hu4_H', 'hu5_H', 'hu7_X'

print(sum(item1 == item2 for item1, item2 in zip(x, y)))
# 3
```

This works because, in Python, `True` and `False` can be treated as `1` and `0` respectively. So, we can simply compare the corresponding elements and the result of that evaluation can be added together to get the total match count.